# Having trouble connecting to MongoDB with Java

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to write a Java program that will connect to a MongoDB database. I already have the IP address, port, userDB, username, and password of the database I'm trying to access.

I have the mongodb-driver-3.0.0.jar file set as a referenced library in Eclipse. I created a MongoDBDriver.java file in the src folder (shown below):

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoDBDriver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("10.66.80.152", 27017);
    String connectPoint = client.getConnectPoint();
    System.out.println(connectPoint);
    client.close();
  }

}
```

When I run the script, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     
com/mongodb/connection/BufferProvider
at MongoDBDriver.main(MongoDBDriver.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  
com.mongodb.connection.BufferProvider
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

So, what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Check this http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html it may help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exception means that you have the class path mismatch.
I create small app that connect java and mongodb and do some CURD operations.

[eMongoDB-Java-app](https://github.com/YasithaBangamuwage/MongoDB-Java-app)
I think it will be better solution to connect database.

Comment: Thanks! I just downloaded the app and it seems great, but I'm still not able to access the database. I added the following code to the MongoDBManager.java file:                                                              `// connect to mongodb server
    mongo = new MongoClient("10.66.80.152", 27017);
    
    // connect with the database
    mongoMgr = mongo.getDB("mbe");
       
    boolean auth = mongoMgr.authenticate("mbeuser", "password".toCharArray());    
     if(auth){
     System.out.println("authorized");
    } else {
     System.out.println("not authorized"); }`

Comment: and I got the following error message: `com.mongodb.MongoException: not authorized for query on mbe.user`

Comment: Did you check 'mbeuser' user privileges?

Answer (score 0):

`MongoClient` does not have method `getConnectPoint()`, class `Mongo` does.

You can read the official website, it will help you out.[mongodb official website java tutorial](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/2.13/getting-started/quick-tour/)