# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/BufferProvider

Tags: java, mongodb, servlets

I'm trying to connect to mongoDB server from Java Servlet.
I added the following jars: **bson-3.0.4.jar, mongodb-driver-3.0.4-javadoc.jar, mongodb-driver-core-3.0.4.jar** and add this jars also to `WEB-INF\lib` directory.
And when i tried to run the following code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
```

I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/connection/BufferProvider
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you check out here, i think you need additional jar file.

http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/#mongodb-driver

also checkout this link [Having trouble connecting to MongoDB with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953711/having-trouble-connecting-to-mongodb-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't it be better to use a dependency management like Maven or Gradle? I prefer to delegate someone else to resolve my dependencies...